# How to delete printers in the Registry in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printer, windows-registry

How to delete printers in the Registry in Windows 7?

Comment: You delete the printer from `Device and Printers`

Comment: For a batch scripted solution, you can also use the interface `Rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry` which is the same as old Windows XP systems.  Also, VBscript is very quick to delete printers, even thought those systems do not always works.  see https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee624057%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For local printers:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows NT x86\Drivers\Version-3\
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\

For network printers:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Providers\LanMan Print Services\Servers\Printers\

Hope this helps

Comment: Is this guaranteed by some documentation, or does it just happen to work on your particular system? If it is guaranteed, please link to references; if not, please state so in the answer.